# How prove this $\frac{af(a)+bf(b)}{a+b}\ge f(a+b)$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Assume that 
$f(x)$ has two derivatives  on $(0,2)$ and $0<a<b<a+b<2$.

I have to prove that, if $f(a)\ge f(a+b)$ and $f''(x)\le 0$, then:

$$\dfrac{af(a)+bf(b)}{a+b}\ge f(a+b).$$

---

I think we also have

$$f(b)\ge f(a+b)$$
so
$$af(a)+bf(b)\ge af(a+b)+bf(a+b)=(a+b)f(a+b)$$

But if this true, then we can prove it.

Answer (score 12):

$f$ is a concave function in virtue of $f''(x)\leq 0$.

Assuming $f(b)<f(a+b)$, somewhere between $b$ and $a+b$ we must have $f'(\xi)>0$.

Moreover, somewhere between $a$ and $b$ we have $f'(\eta)<0$, since $f(a)>f(b)$.

So, somewhere between $\eta$ and $\xi$ we have $f''(\nu)>0$, contradiction.

This proves $f(b)\geq f(a+b)$.

Comment: Wa! It's Nice Nice!+1

Answer (score 1):

Let's $l(x)=cx+d$ be the line that passes through points $(a,f(a))$ and $(a+b,f(a+b))$.

As $f(a)\ge f(a+b)$(therefore $l(a)\ge l(a+b)$) we have that for every $a\le x\le a + b$ $l(x)\ge l(a+b)$, in particular $l(b)\ge l(a+b)$.

But since $f$ is concave $f(b)\ge l(b)\ge l(a+b)= f(a+b).$